# XDebug - Disable writing traces to file

Tags: php, xdebug, trace

I have XDebug configured in PHP with the following settings

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=1000
xdebug.var_display_max_data=100000
xdebug.var_display_max_children=10000
xdebug.auto_trace=On
xdebug.collect_includes=On
```

After a short period of time, it created 17GB of trace files in /tmp :)

I really don't care to have trace written to file.  How can I turn that feature off?

Changing `xdebug.auto_trace` to `off` seems to work, I don't think that's the correct way.  The docs says that's for allowing for traces when auto_prepend is used, and I'm using auto_prepend in my project so would like traces to begin before those files are prepended.

Answer (score 2):

The `xdebug.auto_trace` setting is the correct one. You need to set that to "On" (default is "Off") to make traces. If you don't want traces anymore, you need to turn it "Off" again.

The docs only say that it makes it **possible** to trace function through auto_prepend. Without it, it won't trace functions in auto_prepend files, but functions *are* traced in the normal part of the script.

Comment: `auto_trace` no longer exists in Xdebug 3

Answer (score 0):

xdebug.auto_trace is required for the auto prepend stuff.

Try this( from the docs)

```
xdebug.default_enable
Type: boolean, Default value: 1
```

If this setting is 1, then stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event. You can disable showing stacktraces from your code with xdebug_disable(). As this is one of the basic functions of Xdebug, it is advisable to leave this setting set to 1.

Comment: `auto_trace` no longer exists in Xdebug 3